# What data type is required to store a byte array in JanusGraph?

Tags: arrays, schema, blob, janusgraph

When automatic schema creation is on, I am able to store and retrieve byte arrays in properties, like:

```
byte[] myArray = new byte[10];
vertex.property("blob", myArray);
myArray = vertex.value("blob");
```

However I don't seem to find the correct property definition for when automatic is off. I've already tried `Byte.class` with `Cardinality.LIST`, it comes up with:

```
org.janusgraph.core.SchemaViolationException: Value [[B@a9153e9] is not an instance of the expected data type for property key [payload] and cannot be converted. Expected: class java.lang.Byte, found: class [B
```

Also `Byte[].class` is not supported.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a supported data type: class [Ljava.lang.Byte;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not explicitly mentioned in the JanusGraph docs, but you can just define the data type as `byte[]` like this:

```
gremlin> mgmt = graph.openManagement()
==>org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@6cae2e4d
gremlin> mgmt.makePropertyKey('blob').dataType(byte[].class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
==>blob
gremlin> mgmt.commit()
==>null
```

Now, you can use it in your Gremlin traversals:

```
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardjanusgraph[berkeleyje:/opt/janusgraph/conf/../db/berkeley], standard]
gremlin> g.addV().property('blob', new byte[10])
==>v[4272]
gremlin> g.V(4272).values('blob').next()
==>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Note however that arrays are currently unfortunately not supported via GraphSON in JanusGraph. So, you can basically only use them from Java with Gryo as the serializer right now. See [JanusGraph/janusgraph#1295](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1295) for more information.

`Cardinality.LIST` isn't intended for storing an array of values, but for cases where you just want to have multiple values for the same property, like multiple different addresses for a user for example.